# Symmetrical difference sets $A \bigoplus B$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

Symmetrical difference for two sets I was taught it's defined as this way,

$A\bigoplus B = (x \in A \wedge  x\notin B) \vee (x \notin A \wedge x \in B)$

My question is shouldn't there be a 3rd case where, $x \in A \wedge x \in B$?

Comment: $A\oplus B = (A \setminus B) \cup (B \setminus A) = (A \cup B)\setminus (A \cap B)$ where $A \setminus B = \{x \in A : x \not\in B\}$. If $x \in A \wedge x \in B$, then $x \not\in A \oplus B$.

Comment: The left hand side of the equation seems to be a set while the right hand side is a proposition, those can't be equal. Please fix that! Hint: $A\oplus B = \{\,x \mid \dots \,\}$.

Answer (score 1):

That would be the union of the two sets, which is the disjoint union of their intersection with their symmetric difference. The symmetric difference is a measure of how much the two sets are different. It is minimal (the empty set) when the two sets are equal and it is maximal (the union) when they are disjoint.

Comment: Or to put it a little differently, it’s the set of points that belong to exactly one of the two sets. (+1)